# How do I cancel a close vote?

Tags: support, flagging, vote-to-close

If I have marked any question for close by mistake and it shouldn't be closed, then how can I remove the close vote of mine from that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because many people wished to be able to retract a close vote this feature was introduced recently:

- [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

To undo a close vote we have to click on "close" again to see the following window:

[image]

Note that in case we had selected "Retract Close Vote" there we will not be able to vote to close on this question again or later, even if it was edited for bad.

**This obviously can not be done for a [moderator flag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6210/) we had issued.**

Comment: Note: You've got a broken link there. It should be /a/6210, not /posts/6210.

Comment: @TRiG: thanks!!!

Answer (score 10):

You can't retract flags.

A moderator will see it and likely disagree with it. Assuming that happens that will count against your helpful flag totals but that's rather the point: don't flag things willy-nilly.

I should point out that having declined flags is not the end of the world. Everybody who gets involved in flagging has a few so don't take it as a slap in the face. Just learn from the situation.

Comment: Yeah sir. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Not to mention, its not as bad as when we had flag weight, and you needed a nearly perfect flagging record (and over a thousand flags) to get badges. And we used to walk uphill both ways in the snow...

Comment: Just an FYI, Oli, your answer here is out of date.  :P

Comment: @ThomasW. FYI the question title changed an hour ago from flags to votes. You still can't retract flags.

Comment: @Oli missed that, because `E: Using a phone.` and the "edited X hours ago" doesn't show up very well on the phone :/